# Select what cell class to use in didEndDisplaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

In my tableView I can toggle between two cell classes depending on layout. So now I wonder how I can choose what cell class to select in the `didEndDisplaying` function.

Should I choose cell by using `dequeueReusableCell` like in the function bellow?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isBigCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellBig") as! BigTableViewCell
        cell.myImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSmall") as! SmallTableViewCell
        cell.myImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
    }
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if isBigCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellBig") as! BigTableViewCell

            let data = ads[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            cell.configureWithData(data)

            //Dont show highlight
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSmall") as! SmallTableViewCell

            let data = ads[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            cell.configureWithData(data)

            //Dont show highlight
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            return cell
        }

    }
```

Comment: You already have a reference to your cell in didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, just cast cell as subclass and canceldownloadtask from there

Comment: It's a very bad idea to put the download task in the view (cell). Use `NSOperation` (or a custom class) and a dictionary `[NSIndexPath:NSOperation]` in the view controller.

Comment: @Bseaborn like: (cell as! BigTableViewCell).adImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()  ?

Comment: @vadian what do you mean? I am just following the example in: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Demo/Kingfisher-Demo/ViewController.swift

Comment: If you are using a library there should be a built-in functionality to cancel downloads implicitly.

Comment: How is `isBigCell` supposed to be used? Do you reload the whole table view anytime that value changes? In other words, is the whole table always filled with either "big" cell or "small" cells or is there any time where you have a mix of "big" and "small" cells?

Comment: @rmaddy your updated answer worked. isBigCell is a bool that changes when the user clicks on a button. Then I reload the tableview so I only use one cell type at the time, either all small or all big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell is given to you in the `didEndDisplaying` method. You determine its real type based on the `indexPath`, just like you did in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Do not dequeue another cell in `didEndDisplaying`. Just cast the provided `cell` based on the `indexPath`.

Since it seems that you don't use `indexPath` to determine then cell type, then your code should be something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isBigCell {
        if let bigcell = cell as? BigTableViewCell {
            bigcell.myImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        }
    } else {
        if let smallcell = cell as? SmallTableViewCell {
            smallcell.myImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like: (cell as! BigTableViewCell).adImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()  ?

Comment: Something like that but you need to decide whether it's a `BigTableViewCell` or a `SmallTableViewCell` based on the `indexPath`.

Comment: How do I check it based on the **indexPath**? If I use the code I provided in my question it doesnt crash but if I switch it to (cell as! BigTableViewCell).adImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask() and (cell as! SmallTableViewCell).adImageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask() it craches because it cant cast the cell

Comment: It would be easier to explain if you update your question with your `cellForRowAt` method.